# How to use TypeScript Map with error handlers?

Tags: typescript

Why does TypeScript complain about this code ?

```
class FooError extends Error {
}

const map = new Map<ErrorConstructor, any> ([
  [Error, 'do this'],
  [FooError, 'do that']
])
```

> Type 'typeof FooError' is not assignable to type 'ErrorConstructor'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let's look at the definition of `ErrorConstructor`:

```
interface ErrorConstructor {
    new(message?: string): Error; // is a constructor
    (message?: string): Error; // is callable
    readonly prototype: Error; // has an Error prototype
}
```

So, an `ErrorConstructor` needs to be a constructor which takes an optional string argument, and it also needs to be callable as a function, and it needs to have an `Error` prototype.  Let's look at your `FooError` class:

```
class FooError extends Error {
}
FooError.prototype; // okay, type FooError
new FooError("okay"); // okay
FooError("oops"); // error
```

It has a `FooError` prototype, which is fine since `FooError` is a subtype of `Error`.  It is a constructor, and it does accept an argument since it defers to the superclass `Error`, which is an `ErrorConstructor`.  But it's not callable as a function.  So `FooError` is not an `ErrorConstructor`.

---

At this point, you need to decide if you actually *care* about it being an `ErrorConstructor`.  Do you plan to call it as `FooError('msg')` instead of `new FooError('msg')`?  I doubt it.  For that matter, do you care that the constructor's `prototype` is of type `FooError`?  Probably not.  In that case, don't use `ErrorConstructor`.  Instead, use the following interface which only cares about being an optional-one-string-arg constructor:

```
interface NoFrillsErrorConstructor {
  new(message?: string): Error;
}
```

Now your code will work:

```
const map = new Map<NoFrillsErrorConstructor, any> ([
  [Error, 'do this'],
  [FooError, 'do that']
])
```

And all will be well, as long as you only use the map's keys as constructors:

```
map.forEach((val, err) => {
  err.prototype; // exists, but is type any.  Who cares, right?
  new err(); // okay
  err(); // not okay
})
```

(If you *do* care about `FooError` conforming to `ErrorConstructor`, that can be arranged, but it's a bit more annoying.  Let me know if you'd like me to elaborate.)

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!